# C - Can you free individual memory adresses of an array allocated dynamically?

Tags: c, memory, allocation

i do not seem to find an answer to this question. Why you cant free up an individual adress is it because the space needs to be continuous? and if this is the answer then why fragmentation occurs on Hard-Disks

Comment: `space needs to be continuous` - right one

Comment: fragmentation on hard drive occurs exactly because hd allows to "free" space between blocks, ie delete any file

Comment: Because it is implemented this way. Implementing it so every individual byte can be freed will add *much* of overhead for the bookkeeping.

Comment: You can `munmap` a memory page in the middle of a large `mmap` segment.

Comment: You could implement your own replacements for `malloc` and `free` with this capability. I suspect that somewhere during the process of doing so, you will have understood why this is not a commonly-supported feature. But it would be possible. =)

Comment: If the individual memory addresses are at the end of the array, `realloc` can do this.

Comment: Comment - only the virtual address space is continuous, the physical memory for an array can be a set of scattered 4 KB pages, and requires virtual to physical mapping for a process or thread to access that memory. If doing DMA type I/O, the buffer's virtual address space has to be mapped into a set of physical memory offsets and lengths, based on the 4 KB pages or portions of those pages.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Can you free individual memory adresses of an array allocated dynamically?</sub>

If the memory is at the end of an array, you can free off the unneeded excess by performing a `realloc` to a smaller size, with the caveat that you may actually get a new pointer to new memory with the prefix contents copied into it, and the original memory freed in its entirety.

Otherwise, no. The `free` interface is defined to only accept addresses returned from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

> <sub>Why you cant free up an individual adresss is it because the space needs to be continuous?</sub>

Well, the direct answer is that there is no interface defined to do so. There is no way to tell `free` how much of the pointer you passed in should be freed. If you want to free all memory to the end of the allocated block, `realloc` does that.

If contiguity is not important to your program, just use separate allocations for each array element, and free them individually.

> <sub>and if this is the answer then why fragmentation occurs on Hard-Disks</sub>

One way to imagine a scenario of fragmentation on a file system is that if three files are created one after another, and then the middle one is deleted, there is now a hole between two files.

```
|---File 1---|--- Hole ---|---File 3---|
```

Now suppose a new file is created, so it starts out inside the hole between the two files, but as it grows, it cannot fit in the hole, so now the rest of the file is after `File 3`. In this case, we would say the new file is fragmented.

```
|---File 1---|---File 4...|---File 3---|...File 4---|
```

This happens on "Hard-Drives" because a *filesystem* is designed that way: allow a large file to span the available holes in the physical medium.

A RAM disk used for a filesystem would also eventually have fragmented files.

A non-contiguous data structure could be considered to be "fragmented", e.g., a linked-list or a tree, but that is by design. An array is considered contiguous by its very definition. However, files on a filesystem are not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, the reason you cannot release individual portions of allocated memory is that it is not useful enough to justify writing the software to support it.

The C standard specifies services provided by `malloc`, `free`, `realloc`, and related routines. The only provisions it makes for releasing space are by using `free` to release an allocation and by using `realloc` to replace an allocation with a smaller one.

C implementations are free to extend the C standard by providing services to release portions of allocated space. However, I am not aware of any that have done so. If a program were allowed to free arbitrary pieces of memory, the memory management software would have to keep track of all of them. That requires extra data and time. Additionally, it can interfere with some schemes for managing memory. Memory management software might organize memory so that allocations of particular sizes can be satisfied quickly out of specialized pools, and having to take back an arbitrary sized portion that was part of a specialized pool could be a problem.

If there were a demand for such a service, it could be written. But programs and algorithms have evolved over the years to use the existing services, and there does not seem to be much need to release individual portions of allocations. Generally, if a program is going to work with many objects that it might free individually, it allocates them individually. This is common when building data structures of all sorts, using pointers to construct trees, hashed arrays of lists or other structures, and so on. Data structures are often built out of individual nodes that can be allocated or freed individually. So there is little need to carve individual pieces to be released out of larger allocations.

The organization of memory has very little to do with the organization of data on hard disk or other storage media. Data is generally transferred between arbitrary places on disk and arbitrary places in memory as needed. In a variety of circumstances, files are “memory mapped,” meaning that the contents of a file are made visible in memory so that one can read the file contents by reading memory and one can modify the file by modifying memory. However, even in this situation, there is not generally any relationship between where the blocks of the file are on disk and where the blocks of the file are in memory. The blocks of a file are managed by the file system and are not necessarily contiguous, and the blocks in memory are managed by the memory system and may be rearranged arbitrarily with support from virtual memory hardware.

Answer (score 0):

First question NO as you can only free the whole memory allocated by one malloc family function

Fragmentation of hard disks does not have anything common with the memory allocations.

Comment: First question was "why?".

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation is handled as seemingly continuous blocks of memory (it might not be in physical memory though, but that's not relevant).

There is no simple way to "cut a hole" in a single memory allocation, but you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 11

int main (void)
{
    char *array;

    array = (char *) malloc(ARRAY_LEN);
    strcpy(array,"0123456789");

    printf("%s\n",array);

    //Remove the 5th element:
    memmove(&array[5], &array[5+1], ARRAY_LEN-5);
    array = realloc(array, ARRAY_LEN-1);
    printf("%s\n",array);

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Some Linux filesystems allows for "punching holes" in files, so with a mmap'ed file, you might be able to use the `fallocate` systemcall on it while using it as an array in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you free individual memory adresses of an array allocated dynamically?

You seem to recognize that the answer is "no", because you follow up with

> Why you cant free up an individual adress is it because the space needs to be continuous?

Each individual allocation is continuous, but the union of all dynamically-allocated space is by no means certain to be continuous.  More on this later.

At the most practical level, you cannot free chunks of a larger allocation because C provides no mechanism for doing so.  In particular, among [the specifications for the `free()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2) is:

> if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, `free()` exhibits UB if its argument is a pointer into the interior of an allocated block.

Note also that `free()` accepts only one parameter.  It makes no provision for the caller to specify the amount of memory to free, so the memory-management subsystem has to figure that out from the argument argument presented.  That's fine for the operating model that one frees only whole, previously-allocated blocks, but it does not easily support freeing an allocation in multiple pieces.

Furthermore, consider that although you cannot free specific chunks of a larger allocation, you *can* use `realloc()` to reduce the the size of an allocation (which may also involve moving it).

Anything beyond that is in the realm of implementation-specific behavior, but do bear in mind that

- it is very common for allocation to be performed and accounted for in terms of multi-byte blocks -- for example, multiples of 16 bytes -- regardless of the specific sizes requested.  An implementation that works this way cannot under any circumstances free partial blocks, though one could imagine being able to free individual blocks from a larger allocation.
- some implementations store memory management metadata adjacent to the dynamically-allocated space presented to the program.  In such an implementation, it is not useful to free pieces of a larger allocation because they cannot, in general, be reused until the whole allocation is freed, for there is no available place for the needed metadata.

> and if this is the answer then why fragmentation occurs on Hard-Disks

You don't need to free allocations in pieces to get memory fragmentation.  It can suffice to perform multiple allocations and afterward free only some of them.  This is a real issue that can degrade performance and even cause programs to fail.

With that said, however, file systems typically use different methods and data structures for tracking their metadata than do C memory-management implementations, and the underlying hardware has different characteristics and behavior, so there's really no justification for forming expectations about the behavior and capabilities of one variety of storage based on the behavior and capabilities of the other.